# Vue.js. Мне нужна анимация/переходы при загрузке и скролле страницы . Как это реализовать? И мог бы Animate css справится с задачей? Проект на vue.js

Tags: vue.js

Vue.js. Мне нужна анимация/переходы при загрузке и скролле страницы . Как это реализовать? И мог бы Animate css справится с задачей? Проект на vue.js

Comment: [Возможный ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17633941) на ваш вопрос

Answer (score 2):

В документации подробно расписано про анимацию переходов между страницами:
https://router.vuejs.org/ru/guide/advanced/transitions.html
https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html

Если вкратце, можно работать с этими классами:

```
.page-enter-active, .page-leave-active {
  transition: all .3s ease;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translate(0, -5%);
}
```

A router-view завернуть в transition:

```
<transition name="page">
  <router-view/>
</transition>
```

Это всё находится примерно в /src/App.vue (или другом корневом компоненте, где используется router-view)